# Access FritzBox via HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit, fritzbox

I am trying to access my FritzBox via HTMLUnit, but got error that my browser was too old and not supported.

```
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://fritz.box/");
System.out.println(page1.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a nice riddle and because i also have a frizbox here please open an inssue on github and i will try to figure out what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

From a first analysis:
The UI does some browser checks to make sure the used features are supported by your browser.

The check looks like this (see js/browser.js)

```
var ok = true,
    gNbc;
try {
    if (!gNbc) {
        ok = ok && window.Proxy && typeof new window.Proxy({}, function() {}) === "object";
        ["1"].forEach(function() {});
        ok = ok && window.Promise && typeof new window.Promise(function() {}) === "object";
        ok = ok && window.Blob && typeof new window.Blob(["<a></a>"], {
            type: "text/html"
        }) === "object";
        ok = ok && window.requestAnimationFrame && true;
        ok = ok && window.Promise.resolve(true).finally(function() {});
    }
} catch (err) {
    ok = false;
}
if (!ok) {
    window.location.href = "sorry.lua";
}
```

HtmlUnit (as of version 2.56) does not support javascript Proxy's and that is the reason this check fails and finally you are redirected to /sorry.lua.

Again - please open an issue at https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit.